Espressif-IDE import RainMaker example prokect cannot build or clean
Hardware: ESP32-C3-DevKitM-1
IDE: Espressif-IDE
OS: Windows 11
Issue: when I build & run esp-idf examples (e.g. \esp-idf-v5.3\examples\peripherals\adc), everything is fine. However, IDE failed to import & build & clean ESP32 RainMaker example projects (\esp-idf-v5.3\esp-rainmaker\examples\led_light).
Detailed steps:
1. Open ESP-IDF 5.3 CMD terminal
2. Download ESP32 RainMaker repo from GitHub:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/espressif/esp-rainmaker.git


3. In Espressif-IDE, Project Explorer, right click to import RainMaker example project \esp-idf-v5.3\esp-rainmaker\examples\led_light


Build & clean RainMaker example project showed fail messages.

Build error message: Directory specified in EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS doesn't exist: C:/Users/StevenWang/components/esp-insights/components
Clean error message: ninia: error: loading "build,ninja': The system cannot find the file specified


